# Import result from Chainlink function to checkUpkeep()

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'd like to import a uint256 variable A I've got from the chainlink function into the checkUpkeep() function for threshold checking. For example, if variable A is larger than some threshold, then performUpkeep().

In the [AutomatedFunctionsConsumer.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/contracts/AutomatedFunctionsConsumer.sol) there are checkUpkeep() and performUpkeep() and generatefunction but I'm not quite sure about the implementation. Any idea and suggestion is appreciated, many thanks,

Comment: are you able to be more specific in your question? if you've got Variable A, maybe store it in storage and then your automation will check against that?